# NetBeans 8.1 Java - how to add Command-line arguments when you want to run java file

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Please, how can I add  Command-line arguments to a java file which I would like to run in NetBeans 8.1?

Edit #1: added screenshot
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "arguments to a java file"? Command-line arguments? function arguments?

Comment: sorry, yes I mean Command-line arguments from NetBeans (added to original post)

Answer (score 0):

For a **web application**, you can initialize some parameters with 
`<init-param>` or `<context-param>` in `web.xml`, or use a `ServletContextListener`.

For a **command line** application:

Right click on the project node, select Properties.
Choose Run category.

[image: Command line arguments]

Comment: yes, that is what I tried,..but you can see my options (added to original post)

Comment: You have chosen a web application, not a command line application.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a maven project you could use a exec-maven-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.something.Main</mainClass><!--change to your class with main method here-->
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-r</argument><!-- argument -r -->
                    <argument>bar</argument><!-- argument bar -->
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```